# Changing link color on the socialstatistics-widget

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I have implemented the widget on my Tumblr blog and tried to change the link blue color in the widget but had no luck so far. This is the code they facilitate:

Link to the blog: http://eduardo-mateos.tumblr.com/

```
<div class="socialstatistics-widget" data-id="xxxxxxxxxx"></div><script>(function(d,t){var b=d.createElement(t),c=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];b.async=b.src="http://socialstatistics.com/widget/widget.min.js";c.parentNode.insertBefore(b,c);})(document,'script');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert something like

```
.socialstatistics-widget a {
 color:#FF0000 !important;
}
```

in your CSS file, or style tag, where FF0000 is your custom color.

Comment: No, already tried that without luck. Here's a link in case it helps better: http://eduardo-mateos.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
#socialstatisticswidget a:link, .socialstatisticswidgetrow a:link, #socialstatisticswidget a:visited, .socialstatisticswidgetrow a:visited, #socialstatisticswidget a:active, .socialstatisticswidgetrow a:active {
    color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

That one should work. I found it right inside the widget, you should just rewrite this css in your file.